# SSRS Report takes a long time to OPEN (not run)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a few reports on the SSRS Reporting server. The reports are in different folders, all accessing the same shared data source in the Datasource folder.  They all work fine. All except for one report.

That one report is NOT much different from two other reports that work fine. This report, in question, won't even open. I'm not talking about RUNNING the report. I'm talking about clicking on the link for that report to OPEN it. It takes a few hours to OPEN that report.

I downloaded the .rdl file for that report, renamed a copy and uploaded it to the same folder, and that produces no difference. The copy won't open either.

We don't have Report Builder so it can't automatically open in Report Builder. But when I download the report, it's definition opens in Visual Studio.

The report does have a few parameters but the report won't even open so can't even get to the part where you can select the parameters. I'm wondering if anyone can shed light on why that particular report won't even open.

Comment: Are there any parameters that query datasources? Does it open in Report Builder or VS where you created it from?

Comment: We don't have Report Builder so it can't automatically open in Report Builder. But when I download the report, it's definition opens in Visual Studio.

The report does have a few parameters but the report won't even open so can't even get to the part where you can select the parameters.

Comment: When you open a report, one of the first things it does is execute any dataset queries that are used to populate parameter values so it may be there that's the problem. When you say it won't open in VS, do you mean you can;t even get to the designer, or the report won't run?

If you can't get to the designer then it sounds really broke! In any case you could edit the rdl file in a text editor and look at report design from there which might be useful if you have to build it from scratch again.

Comment: I can download the report and the report definition OPENS in Visual Studio. The previous guy created the report using an XML Code generator. Other reports created in the same way work fine. Can't read much from the XML. I can recreate the report but I will only be assuming what the conditions and parameters are.

Comment: Report Builder 3 is free. FYI.